# We got new laptops, our wireless performance suddenly sucks, and it appears that every laptop is trying to adhoc network?

Tags: wifi

We have intel centrino advanced-n 6205 hardware.  Our wireless infrastructure hasn't changed a bit.  A buddy here at work used Kismet for Mac OS X and detected hundreds of ad hoc wireless networks.  Does anyone know if this card has some sort of ad hoc networking enabled by default?  I would think if each laptop were advertising ad hoc networking it would slow things down considerably.

I'm a developer by trade and networking is not my day job.  I'm just trying to figure out if this is a possibility so I can open a ticket and hopefully jump start the process of getting this corrected by our networking group.

We are running Windows 7 Enterprise with a custom image.  We are using the Intel ProSET/Wireless software version 14.3.0.0.

Comment: Sounds like a couple of busy-bodies poking around in things they have no business poking around in. 1. Have you verified what your buddy has told you for yourself? 2. How do you know he knows what he's talking about and looking at? 3. How do you know that the wireless infrastructure hasn't changed if you're not in the networking group? 4. Why not take your question directly to the networking group as opposed to posting your hypothesis here?

Comment: I can poke around in anything I like.  I'm an engineer.  It's what I do.  I've seen the kismet scan results.  My fellow teammate is far better versed in wireless network stuff than I am.  I'll take his word for it since he has no incentive to lie to me.  He's pretty good about speaking up when he simply doesn't know something.  I've asked a couple of engineers here locally about our wireless network and they've reported no changes.  Lastly, I'm asking here because I'm interesting in learning more about this topic and potentially helping solve a problem.

Comment: You're an engineer (congratulations) but you're not in the networking group, which is the group responsible for the wireless infrastructure. My first inclination when I have questions or concerns about something that falls outside of the responsibility of my department is to ask someone in the department that is responsible for the thing I have questions or concerns with, not to post my question to a web site, hoping to surreptitiously sidestep the group that is responsible. I believe your intention is good, but your method of approach smacks of sneakiness.

Comment: You seem very territorial.  I'm glad I don't work with you.

Comment: @JimmyMiller: Can you get post some screenshots, logs, etc, of what your coworker is seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a little more detail (i.e. OS, OEM install vs. custom image)? But to answer your question, I have never seen a new laptop come out of the box with an ad-hoc network set up. It's all typically handled by the operating system, and not really dependent on the wireless chipset.

Comment: Update the question with more detail.